# How can I add more padding to tree chart in echartjs?

Tags: javascript, charts, visualization

For some tools, we use tree chart from echartjs .

Everything works fine but I have one problem and it is the size of padding in tree chart.

As you can see in this image everything is fine, but I can't enable more padding to this chart :
i want this chart for my friend website ([امروز چندمه](http://8box.ir/time/today))

[image]

And this is my code :

```
myChart.showLoading();
$.get('data/asset/data/flare.json', function (data) {
    myChart.hideLoading();

    echarts.util.each(data.children, function (datum, index) {
        index % 2 === 0 && (datum.collapsed = true);
    });

    myChart.setOption(option = {

        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'item',
            triggerOn: 'mousemove'
        },

        series:[
            {
                type: 'tree',

                data: [data],

                top: '1%',
                left: '15%',
                bottom: '1%',
                right: '7%',

                symbolSize: 7,

                orient: 'RL',

                label: {
                        position: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        align: 'left'
                },

                leaves: {
                    label: {
                            position: 'left',
                            verticalAlign: 'middle',
                            align: 'right'
                    }
                },

                expandAndCollapse: true,
                animationDuration: 550,
                animationDurationUpdate: 750
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: can  you check the css element corresponding to it and override the css properties to have padding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the values of the `top` and `bottom` properties to negative values, and the `left` and `right` properties to larger positive values.

For example, set `top : -10%` and `bottom: -15%`. Then `Right: 20%` and `left:15%`. You will have to try different values until you find a combination that suits your situation.The higher the right and left values, and the lower the top and bottom values, the more pronounced the effect. That is, making your chart taller and narrower, thus spacing or padding out the values.

You could also reduce the value of the `symbolSize` property e.g to 1.

Here is the link to the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codekip/89mLaoh7/3/)

Comment: I try but i can't do this, can you explain your code in jsfiddle ?

Comment: @majid i've added the link to the fiddle in my answer. In the fiddle, look for the comment "CHANGE THESE VALUES TO SEE EFFECT"

Answer (score 1):

Echart `version 4` removed the padding option from the nodes. I also tried to fix this but there is an issue on echart [github](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/7767). You can use other features like mouseOver.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like in Echart `version 4` there is no way to define padding for nodes
But there is a way to avoid collapsing of nodes.

This tree is gonna take as much space (width and height) as you allow it to take.
So you can just specify bigger height value for outer `div`. And then `overflow: auto`; for next `div`.

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
 <div style="min-height:2000px">
  <EchartsSVG/>
 </div>
</div>
```

You can create a formula to count your nodes and calculate `min-height`